# Render XML with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, soap, web, service

I have the following XML;

```html
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
<GetAllUserCollectionFromWebResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/">
  <GetAllUserCollectionFromWebResult>
    <GetAllUserCollectionFromWeb>
      <Users>
        <User ID="Value" Sid="Value" Name="Value" LoginName="Value" Email="Value" Notes="" IsSiteAdmin="False" IsDomainGroup="False" Flags="0" />
        <User ID="Value" Sid="Value" Name="Value" LoginName="Value" Email="Value" Notes="" IsSiteAdmin="True" IsDomainGroup="False" Flags="0" />
      </Users>
    </GetAllUserCollectionFromWeb>
  </GetAllUserCollectionFromWebResult>
</GetAllUserCollectionFromWebResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I've tried rendering the XML with XSL to output specific values; e.g. the LoginName.

This is my XSL;

```html
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">

  <xsl:for-each select="Envelope/soap:Body/GetAllUserCollectionFromWebResponse/GetAllUserCollectionFromWebResult/GetAllUserCollectionFromWeb/Users/User">  
      
      <xsl:value-of select="@LoginName" />

  </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Nothing is outputted, I simply want to output the LoginName attribute.

Please helps,

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two errors:

The soap namespace uri in your XSL misses the trailing `/`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet ...
     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```

In your XPath for the user the location steps `GetAllUserCollectionFromWebResponse` etc. need a namespace prefix mapped to URI `http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/`

```
<xsl:for-each xmlns:dir="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/" 
    select="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/dir:GetAllUserCollectionFromWebResponse/dir:GetAllUserCollectionFromWebResult/dir:GetAllUserCollectionFromWeb/dir:Users/dir:User">
```